# An unreaped child and its future

Tags: c, signals, freebsd, zombie-process, sigchld

So when a child dies parent gets `SIGCHLD` but if parent dies before doing wait(), the child is reparented to `init`. At this point in time the child is a `zombie` i.e. `<defunct>`.

What happens next?

Does `init` do wait() on that child? if yes, when does it do it? Any guarantees regarding time-limit?

Comment: Not sure about your wording, but to clarify, the child is a zombie for time between its death and the time its parent (either the original parent, or init ) waits on it.  The wording of your question implies the child only becomes a zombie after the parent dies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `init` will immediately reap all children.  If you make a process which ignores `SIGCHLD` and accumulates many zombies you can get rid of them by killing that parent via the mechanism you describe.

For reference here is the main loop of `init` while in multi user mode.  `requested_transition` is set by signalling `init` (e.g. the classic `kill -1 1` to read an updated `inittab`):

```
    while (!requested_transition)
            if ((pid = waitpid(-1, (int *) 0, 0)) != -1)
                    collect_child(pid);
```

(`collect_child` handles cases where init has some special interest in the process, such as a login shell which now needs a new `getty`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ben. If `init` is going to reap immediately, does it make no sense to define an explicit handler for SIGCHLD to do wait()? I experienced that having such a handler is very useful. It does "reap"ing much quicker than `init`. Do you agree?

Comment: If your process is *still alive* it is up to you to reap.  Leaving zombies around until your process exits is bad.  If it's an unlimited number you can run yourself out of procs.

Comment: Thanks Ben. BTW, I am not following the code snippet you provided. It looks intriguing though :) Can you please elaborate on that? I am looking at freebsd source and not finding such code block.

Comment: That's from `/usr/src/sbin/init/init.c` and it's a loop of `waitpid()` (fancier `wait()`) until a signal handler asynchronously sets `requested_transition`.  When the kernel reparents a process to `init` it wakes up in that loop.  The zombie goes away after the wait:  The purpose of the zombie is to retain the state that `waitpid()` can receive.